# dimple.js aggregating non-numerical values

Tags: data-visualization, dimple.js

Say i have a csv containing exactly one column `Name`, here's the first few values:

```
Name
A
B
B
C
C
C
D
```

Now i wish to create a bar plot using `dimple.js` that displays the distribution of the `Name` (i.e the count of each distinct `Name`) but i can't find a way to  do that in dimple without having the actual counts of each name. I looked up the documentation of `chart.addMeasureAxis`(
https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addMeasureAxis) and found that for the measure argument:

*measure (Required): This should be a field name from the data. If the field contains numerical values they will be aggregated, if it contains any non-numeric values the distinct count of values will be used.*

So basically what that says is it doesn't matter how many times each category occurred, dimple is just going to treat each of them as if they occurred once ??

I tried the following `chart.addMeasureAxis('y', 'Name')` and the result was a barplot that had each bar at value of `1` (i.e each name occurred only once).

Is there a way to achieve this without changing the data set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need something else in your data which distinguishes the rows:

e.g.

```
Type    Name
X       A
Y       A
Z       A
X       B
Y       B
A       C
```

You could do it with:

```
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Name");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Type");
```

or add a count in:

```
Name    Count
A       1
A       1
A       1
B       1
B       1
C       1
```

Then it's just

```
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Name");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Count");
```

But there isn't a way to do it with just the name.

Comment: i didn't understand the `Type` solution, how is type X distinguishing between names A & B ?

Comment: It will count distinct values for Type for each value of Name

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.. First use [d3.nest()](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nest) to get the unique values of the dataset. then add the count of each distinct values to the newly created object.

```
var countData = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d["name];
    })
    .entries(yourDate);

countData.forEach(function (c) {
    c.count = c.values.length;
});
```

after this created the dimple chart from the new "countData Object"

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, countData);
```

Then for 'x' and 'y' axis,

```
myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "key");
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "count");
```

Please look in to [d3.nest()](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nest) to understand the "countData" object.